# How do I use spring boot maven plugin build-image with skaffold and dekorate?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, skaffold

I'm trying to use Skaffold, Dekorate and Spring Boot.

I can't find any examples using the new buildpack feature of Spring Boot 2.3+

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta9
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: tellus-upgrade
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: tellus-admin
      custom:
        buildCommand: ./mvnw -pl tellus-admin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=$IMAGE -Drevision=dev-SNAPSHOT -DskipTests=true
        dependencies:
          paths:
            - tellus-admin/src
            - tellus-admin/pom.xml
    - image: tellus-config-server
      custom:
        buildCommand: ./mvnw -pl tellus-config-server org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=$IMAGE -Drevision=dev-SNAPSHOT -DskipTests=true
        dependencies:
          paths:
            - tellus-config-server/src
            - tellus-config-server/pom.xml
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - kubernetes/defaults.yml
    - kubernetes/db/kubernetes.yml
    - kubernetes/dev/dnsutils.yml
    - kubernetes/kafka-connect/kubernetes.yml
    - tellus-admin/target/classes/META-INF/dekorate/kubernetes.yml
    - tellus-config-server/target/classes/META-INF/dekorate/kubernetes.yml
```

When I run skaffold dev I get the error:
exiting dev mode because first build failed: the custom script didn't produce an image with tag [tellus-config-server:RELEASE_2020_2_0-226-g9be76a373-dirty]

However from the logs it looks like the image was built...

```
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/tellus-config-server:RELEASE_2020_2_0-226-g9be76a373-dirty'
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.004 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-15T22:31:59+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building [tellus-admin]...
exiting dev mode because first build failed: the custom script didn't produce an image with tag [tellus-config-server:RELEASE_2020_2_0-226-g9be76a373-dirty]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image` loads the image into your local Docker daemon, but does not push the image.  I've never tried it, but you might be able to use the `com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:push` goal.

*Update*: here's a Skaffold custom build script that should do the right thing:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd "$BUILD_CONTEXT"
mvn -pl "$1" -Drevision=dev-SNAPSHOT -DskipTests=true \
  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image \
  -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName="$IMAGE"
if [ "$PUSH_IMAGE" = true ]; then
    docker push "$IMAGE"
fi
```

You could save that to a file `mvn-build-image.sh` and then modify your skaffold.yaml like:

```
artifacts:
- image: tellus-admin
  custom:
    buildCommand: ./mvn-build-image.sh tellus-admin
```

---

You might want to look at the [Skaffold's Jib integration](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/jib/) to simplify this process.

Comment: thanks! I got it working eventually without the need to run the docker push - I think I need to run ```eval $(minikube docker-env)```

Comment: Running `eval $(minikube docker-env)` ensures that Skaffold will build using Minikube's packaged docker daemon (not your local docker daemon). Minikube uses images from its own docker daemon when present.  You shouldn't have needed to run that eval expression though as Skaffold normally detects that you're using minikube and configures itself with the values from running `minikube docker-env`.  If you're interested in diagnosing this further, please open an issue at https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/new and include a log of running `skaffold build -v debug`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is based on Paketo/spring-boot-maven-plugin only producing a local container image - and not pushing it as [Brian de Alwis outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864749/4964553) - then [the Image Publishing ability of the spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-example-publish) should do the trick. Therefore simply append the following to your `mvn spring-boot:build-image` command:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true
```

You can also configure the image name like this explicitely:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=docker.example.com/library/tellus-config-server:latest -Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true
```

[As the docs state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-example-publish) you can also configure every aspect of image publishing in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>docker.example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
            <publish>true</publish>
        </image>
        <docker>
            <publishRegistry>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>secret</password>
                <url>https://docker.example.com/v1/</url>
                <email>user@example.com</email>
            </publishRegistry>
        </docker>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With that configuration in place you wouldn't even need to explicitely use the `-Dspring-boot.build-image.publish=true` parameter, since we configured `<image><publish>` to be `true`.

So no need to use Jib or custom build scripts. And there's even [Cloud Native Buildpack support currently in beta for Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/buildpacks/) - so that could be another option to have a look on (because the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is also "only" an abstraction for the Cloud Native Buildpack / Paketo.io integration), if you'd like to switch to [pack CLI](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/).